# Why the modern German government conducts the policy that prevents assimilation of minorities and inter-ethnic mixing?

Tags: germany, racism, demographics

I will name several German policies that make impression the government is striving to prevent inter-ethnic mixing:

- There are lists of permitted names for each ethnicity. One cannot take or give their children a name of their wish which is not listed as permitted.
- All people have their religion registered and the believers have to belong to a church or another religious organization.
- There is a church tax, famously imposed on Christians and Jews but not on Muslims which discourages them from converting.
- When immigrating to Germany (for instance as a Jewish refugee from the former USSR), atheists are not allowed. Each ethnic Jew is required to get registered at a synagoge. Christian Jews are also not allowed.
- Muslim refugees are not allowed to convert from Islam into Christianity in refugee camps, if they violate, they are deported back to their countries.
- To emigrate to Germany one has to prove either German or Jewish blood. Only pre-1991 papers are accepted because some post-Soviet countries allow to change the registered ethnicity according the self-identification. This reminds Nazi Germany where one had to prove their German blood with pre-1871 papers.

Why such policies are conducted?

Comment: Some evidence would be appreciated!

Comment: https://blogs.loc.gov/law/2017/08/naming-laws-in-germany/ - Nothing here about ethnically limited name lists. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law#Germany) says there were such list during the Nazi era, specifically for Jewish and Non-Jewish ethnicity.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are only correct if you give a religion to begin with when you arrive in Germany, and it's chiefly for tax reasons in that it's used to allocate which churches get public funding. If you state atheist on arrival there is no tax and both points are moot. Citations needed for points 1 and 4-6.

Comment: @Jontia http://www.firstnamesgermany.com/the-german-law-on-first-names/

Comment: @Anixx: that link says exactly the opposite of your point 1. "The legal regulations regarding first names are often more generous if one or both parents come from abroad. Naming rules prevelant in the respective country of origin **can be, but do not necessarily have to be taken into consideration**."

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy In order to be allowed to immigrate to Germany a Jew should have an approval from German Jewish community that they are willing to accept him. They do not accept Atheists. The Jew have to remain a member of the community for at least 6 years after arrival until he receives a citizenship.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy this means that the foreigners sometimes can take names of their country of origin, which the Germans would not be allowed to do. Thus, there are ethnic-specific restrictions.

Comment: [Article](https://www.dw.com/en/germanys-atheist-refugees-when-not-believing-is-life-threatening/a-46822315) about Atheist Refugees in Germany. It seems unlikely it can be a reason to claim asylum, but illegal for general migration.

Comment: @Anixx I read the link you posted while finding the wikipedia article and legal blog I posted. Nothing in there mentions any ethnically based restrictions on names.

Comment: @Anixx: No it doesn't. It means muslim migrants can call their son any valid German name, in addition to Mohammed and other muslim boy names. As to your other point, I call BS -- show a proper source.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy but a German cannot call their son "Mohammed". Or say, "Vladimir".

Comment: @Anixx: And? The way your rant masquerading as a question reads, you suggest that children of muslim descendants _must_ get called muslim first names. What the law says is that they _can_ do so, on top of the usual name choices. Germany is far from alone in the world with rules like that. The rules will get relaxed at some point, like they did in France.

Comment: As ethnic Jewish atheist, born in Sowjet Union, not a member of any jewish community, now German citizen, i call BS on that question. Also names are restricted, but only to protect children - whatever that means - and there are many ridicule names like Tverdohleb (russian for "hard bread") that are still allowed. Learned that by choosing name for my daughter...

Comment: @Mikey: by "protecting children" they mean disallowing to call their babies "[Khaleesi](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2019/may/14/latest-game-of-thrones-episode-sends-curveball-to-children-named-khaleesi)" or "[Donald Trump](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/13/world/asia/donald-trump-afghan-baby.html)".

Comment: @Mikey you mean a Jewish immigrant does not have to have approval of German Jewish community?

Comment: @Anixx we, my parents actually, had to show some documents to the german consulate to identify ourself as jews,only my father is "pure" ethnic jew, but an atheist. It was enought to get permanent visa (1996). We still were russian citizens for some time. After 5 years we applied for and got the German citizenship - at that time we had just to fill a form and submit some documents (translated birth cetificates, russian passport copy). Thought in Germany, after settling we were invited to join the local Jewish community - they do help with local laws and language. My father did, i did not.

Answer (score 7):

There is a kernel of truth in most bullet points, but they get distorted through an incomplete understanding of the German system.

- In Germany, children must be given a name of the **appropriate gender**.

  - Giving a name of the wrong gender or a word that is not a name at all would be considered child abuse.
  - This name may come from any ethnic group, but if the registrar is unfamiliar with the name the parents may be asked to substantiate that it is a name of the appropriate gender. (For instance, in Italy Andrea is a male name, in Germany it is a female name.)
  - German parents can name their son Mohammed if they want, but they cannot name him Aisha or Sarah.
- Some but not all organized churches collect **membership fees** through the tax office. This requires taxpayers to state their church membership.

  - Note that this is about membership, not faith or belief.
  - Not **all** Christian and Jewish churches participate in this system, and church membership is distinct from belief.
  - In a similar vein, and not mentioned by you, there is optional religious education in public schools. Only Lutherans and Catholics have anything near complete coverage, other faiths remain special cases.
  - Same for clergy in the armed forces. This may be slowly changing.
  - It is indeed interesting that so far no Muslim church has entered a similar agreement. Getting German Muslims organized that way would greatly benefit their integration.
- Due to the aftermath of WWII, Germany allows immigration by the descendants of ethnic Germans and by Jews from the former Soviet Union. This is seen as a gesture of apology for the Nazi genocide.

  - Other groups will have to go through the **normal** route, either an application for asylum/refugee status or for an immigrant work permit, followed by naturalization after some years.
  - I'm not aware of any case where conversion **by itself** has led to deportation. It doesn't stop deportation, however, and it may be seen as a ploy to gain residency status.
    There is a quote by a [Bavarian politician](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Scheuer#Zur_Fl%C3%BCchtlingskrise) that said approximately "the worst is a soccer-playing [altar server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altar_server) from Senegal who has been here three years, we'll never get him deported."

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the quote from the Bavarian politician.  Worst what?

Comment: @gerrit, the CSU wants to limit the influx of refugees and deport all those who have no ironclad case for asylum/protection in Germany. To them, good refugees are those who can be deported, bad refugees are those who cannot. And a kid several years in a Bavarian village, active in the soccer club and the local catholic parish, even CSU voters do not want to import him.